Why are RabbitMQ queues states always shown as running?(even if they are idle)
i deploy rabbitmq with official community image
(RabbitMQ 4.0.2 Erlang 26.2.5.4)
in queues tab, all states are running:

but in queue details, it shows idle(and it really is):

Even if I create a new queue, its status is displayed as "Running".
I have Durable classic or quorum queues and auto-delete is disable for all queues.
Are there any special settings or tips or just a bug?

Seems like a bug.
I have used RabbitMQ 3.6.10 and it shows running or idle respectively.

